# Computing Galois groups of function fields in sage

Tags: galois-theory, sagemath, function-fields

I found documentation on how to compute galois groups for number fields in sage. Is it possible to do the same for function field extensions? I only need it in the simple case of $t - f(x)$ over $k(t)$ where $k$ is a finite field.

Comment: I can't stop picturing going for drive in the plains and seeing the umbra fields of sage flowering. +1 for learning new things.

Comment: [This question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34288/galois-groups-over-function-fields-%C3%A9tale-fundamental-groups) may be useful. You may need to use MAGMA